# masking the built-in variable with its magic behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to follow this [statement in python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers):

> This variable should be treated as read-only by the user. Don’t explicitly assign a value to it — you would create an independent local variable with the same name masking the built-in variable with its magic behavior.

Comment: 1. your link doesn't work. 2. the explanation looks pretty straight forward, in case you don't know what 'masking' or 'shadowing' is, you can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: What part don't you follow? They explain what the `_` magic variable in the interactive interpreter does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interactive prompt, `_` has "magic" behavior -- it gets set to the value of whatever expression was evaluated last:

```
>>> 3 + 3
6
>>> _
6
```

If, however, you assign something to a variable named `_` yourself, then you only "see" that variable, and the magic variable is hidden ("masked"):

```
>>> _ = 3
>>> 3 + 3
6
>>> _
3
```

This happens because your local variable `_` is unrelated to the variable that has the magic behavior, it just happens to have the same name.

So don't do that, not in the interactive prompt anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says it means; you should not assign anything to the `_` variable as that would hide the *real* magic variable:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> _
2
>>> _ = 'foo'
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> _
'foo'
```

The magic `_` variable stores the result of the last expression that was echoed, but by assigning to `_` you no longer can 'see' this magic variable. Looking up `_` shows whatever value I assigned to it now.

Luckily, you can also *delete* the shadowing `_` name again:

```
>>> del _
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>> _
4
```

Comment: I had to upvote only because of: "It means exactly what it says it means" :) (well, not 'only' but...)